# Replace all html special characters in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I want to truncate a string in Smarty
This is the scenario:
The string is "Test!abc". 
Maximum characters allowed = 5.
Smarty gets string.
If I use `{$string}`, I get the desired result "Test!abc"
If I use `{$string|truncate:5:"..":true}` I get "Test&.."

How can I make truncate after html chars conversion. Prefer not to make it in php.
I know about "replace", but it will look like "|replace..|replace..|......"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
{$string|html_entity_decode:2:"UTF-8"|truncate:5:"...":true|htmlentities:2:"UTF-8"}
```

Comment: @JohnMagnolia I couldn't agree more

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Smarty 3.1 you can have a look at the [unescape](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.unescape.tpl) modifier.

```
{$string|unescape:"entity"|truncate:5}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Smarty 2

Answer (score 1):

In Smarty 2 you can try this one

```
{$string|html_entity_decode|truncate:5}
```